# Is the goat describing min-maxing health vs. magic?

Tags: shovel-knight

In the first village you encounter in Shovel Knight, there is a goat next to the gastronomener talking about choosing between magic and health and then offers to sell you a meal ticket.  I you buy meal tickets to increase your health, will you then only be able to get, effectively, one less magic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you won't. You get meal tickets from him and he doesn't affect your magic (mana pool) which you can increase from the blue wizardy guy on the same screen.

The Goatician has 3 meal tickets you can buy.

Maximum health is 10 and maximum mana is 100 (150 with mana armor).